# Pgfplots, reverse y dir has no effect in 3D matrix plot

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, axis

In the PGFPlots manual, matrix plots are not listed among the 3D plot types. However, they seem to work just fine, especially to plot planar data, except for, apparently, the `y dir=reverse` option which has no effect. Here's an MVE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot3 [matrix plot, point meta=explicit] table[meta=c] {
        x y z c
        0 0 0 1.0
        1 0 0 2.0

        0 1 0 3.0
        1 1 0 4.0
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[y dir=reverse]
      \addplot3 [matrix plot, point meta=explicit] table[meta=c] {
        x y z c
        0 0 0 1.0
        1 0 0 2.0

        0 1 0 3.0
        1 1 0 4.0
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Y axis inversion does not work]

The two plots are identical, except for `y dir=reverse`, which has no effect. Note that `x dir=reverse` and `z dir=reverse` do, in fact, work as intended, this quirk seems to be unique to `y dir`. What can be done to invert the y axis here?

I tried:

- using `yscale=-1`, it flips the whole chart.
- using negative values in `unit vector ratio`, that does not work (scale is completely broken).
- using inverted `ymin/ymax` ranges, but that results in an empty visible range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix plot` is described on page 174-178 in the manual. See the manual for the "why" -here is the important bit about "how":

> ...a matrix plot implicitly sets the options  `\pgfplotsset{ y dir=reverse, axis on top, }`
>
> ...
>
> If you prefer other values, you can and should use the starred version
> `matrix plot*` which does not reconfigure the axis in any way.

The result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot3 [matrix plot, point meta=explicit] table[meta=c] {
        x y z c
        0 0 0 1.0
        1 0 0 2.0

        0 1 0 3.0
        1 1 0 4.0
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot3 [matrix plot*, point meta=explicit] table[meta=c] {
        x y z c
        0 0 0 1.0
        1 0 0 2.0

        0 1 0 3.0
        1 1 0 4.0
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two matrix plots where one is with reversed y-axis]

Comment: Obviously `axis on top` can also be applied to the starred version if wished.

Comment: I had missed that in the manual, thank you!